# C++ convert from int to byte array, then convert that byte array back to int, cause overflow

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, byte, overflow

I'm making a multiplayer game where I use CSocket to send data between server and clients, and I need to transfer raw bytes. So I tested out how to convert from integer to byte array and reverse, this is what I tested:

```
int test1 = 257;
byte bytes[4];
copy(&test1, &test1 + 3, bytes);

int test2;
copy(bytes, bytes + 3, &test2);
cout << "Test " << test2 << endl;
```

The test2 variable when printed out, the value isn't 257 but 1 instead, I think it's because type byte (unsigned char) has size of 256 and it is experiencing an overflow. Is there anyway I can convert properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your code fixed

```
int test1 = 257;
byte bytes[4];
copy((char*)&test1, (char*)&test1 + 4, bytes);

int test2;
copy(bytes, bytes + 4, (char*)&test2);
cout << "Test " << test2 << endl;
```

I convert all the pointers to char pointers, and I use +4 not +3. +3 only copies three bytes so it fails to copy the last byte.

Answer (score 1):

All pointer arithmetic will be done in units of the base type.

For a pointer to `int` (`int*`) then adding `3` will add a byte-offset of `3 * sizeof(int)`.

So the call `copy(&test1, &test1 + 3, bytes)` will copy `3` ***`int`*** values into the four-byte array.

To copy only one `int` then add `1` instead:

```
copy(&test1, &test1 + 1, bytes);
```

---

It might help to see any pointer as a pointer to the first element of an array.

For `&test1` it's could then be seen as a pointer to the first element of an array of a single `int` element.

---

And as mentioned in a comment (thanks for pointing it out john) you only copy *three* bytes from the `bytes` array into `test2`.

The end "iterator" should be one element *beyond* the end, which is a pointer to `bytes[4]`. That is you need

```
copy(bytes, bytes + 4, &test2);
```

Comment: A different `+3` error is made when copying the bytes back to the int

Comment: I also wonder if there's a possible endianess issue with the code. Copying to the bytes array is done as a single int, but copying back is done as bytes.

Comment: @john There shouldn't be any endianness issues, if the copying back and forth is all done on the same system.